# No cube has three ones in its binary representation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It's not too hard to show that there are no perfect cubes which have two ones in their binary representation (i.e. are the sum of two distinct powers of two). I suspect the same is true for three ones, and have written a program which confirms my conjecture until the 25 billionth cube. However, I can't think of how to prove it.

The goal reduces to proving it for odd cases, i.e. that the equation $n^3 = 2^a + 2^b + 1$ has no solutions in the positive integers with $a > b$.

This is what I've tried:

$$
n^3 - 1 = (n - 1)(n^2 + n + 1) = 2^b(2^{a-b} + 1)
$$

Notice that $n-1$ and $2^b$ are even and $n^2 + n + 1$ and $2^{a-b} + 1$ are odd. Then $2 ^ b | n - 1$; let $k$ be a positive integer such that $n - 1 = k 2^b$. Then:

$$
k(n^2 + n + 1) = 2^{a-b} + 1
$$

Since $2^{a-b} + 1$ is odd, $k$ must be odd too. (Notice that this means the choice of $k$ and $b$ must be unique given $n$.)

$k$ cannot be $1$ since otherwise, $n(n+1)$ would have to be a power of two and the only possibility is $n=1$ which clearly does not work.

We can rephrase the question now to say:

> Given an odd $n$, there exist unique integers $k$, $b$ such that $k$ is odd and $n = k2^b + 1$. Show that $k(n^2 + n + 1) - 1$ is not a power of 2.

I don't know if this is helpful though. Any ideas?

Comment: An equivalent phrasing is that no cube has a [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) of 3.

Comment: You can say a little more by looking mod 7; any cube is either congruent to $0$ or $\pm1$, and the powers of $2$ are just $1, 2, 4$ (and you're 'given' a 1 as the low bit). Consider the possibilities and you'll see that you must have $a\neq b\bmod 3$, and you can say a bit more depending on the specific residue of the cube mod $7$.

Comment: Define the “cube detection power” of a positive integer base $b$ as $\frac{b}{|\{k^3 \operatorname{mod} b : k\in\mathbb{Z} \}|}$.  Bases that set records for cube detection power are 4, 7, 9, 27, 36, 63, 117, ..., aka [A330695](https://oeis.org/A330695).  These would be good moduli to use when searching for cubes.

Comment: Thanks, 63 is particularly useful since it is one less a power of two and the powers of two modulo 63 are just 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 and 32, so we can quickly see how many powers of two are needed to reach a particular number. The only cube residue that can be the sum of two powers of 2 and 1 is $35=2^5+2^1+1$, which appears for $n$ 14 modulo 21 (in particular this means $n$ is a multiple of 7). So a and b are 1 and 5 mod 6 (we don't know which is which).

Comment: I've been able to solve the problem by brute force looking at mod 16777215 ($2^{24} -1$): none of the cubic residues can be the sum of two powers of two and one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More general result is given in [*Perfect powers with few binary digits and related Diophantine problems, II*](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ebennett/BeBuMi-Camb-2012.pdf) (2012) by Bennett, Bugeaud and Mignotte, Theorem 1:

> If there exist integers $a>b>0$ and $q\geq 2$ for which
> $$
> x^a+x^b+1=y^q, \text{ with } x\in \{2,3\}
> $$
> then
> $$(x,a,b,y,q)=(2, 5, 4, 7, 2), (2, 9, 4, 23, 2), (3, 7, 2, 13, 3), (2, 6, 4, 3, 4), (4, 3, 2, 9, 2), (4, 3, 2, 3, 4)$$
> or $(x,a,b,y,q)=(2,2t,t+1,2^t+1,2)$, for some integer $t=2$ or $t\geq 4$.

In your case $x=2,q=3$ there are indeed no solutions.

**Edit:** As you noted in comments, there are some typos in the refered article. A newer one on the topic [*Perfect powers with three digits*](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ebennett/BeBu-Math-2014.pdf) (2014) by Bennett and Bugeaud has these corrected.

Comment: Thanks! Just some questions: I don't see why the solutions (4,3,2,9,2),(4,3,2,3,4) are included since $x \in {2, 3}$. Additionally, the solution (2, 6, 4, 9, 2) is not there. What am I missing?

Comment: @qucchia Those look like typos, $(2, 6, 4, 9, 2)$ is of the form $(2,2t,t+1,2^t+1,2)$ for $t=3$, though they excluced $t=3$ for some reason. I've added reference to a newer article without these issues.

Answer (score 3):

What we have found is that for $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$, $$n^3-1=(n-1)(n^2+n+1)=2^p(2^q+1)$$
We can see that $\gcd\left(2^p,2^q+1\right)=1$ and $\gcd(n-1,n^2+n+1)=1$ or $3$.

Since $p,q>0$, it follows that $2^p,2^q+1>1$ so if $\gcd(n-1,n^2-n+1)=1$, $2^p=n-1$ and $2^q+1=n^2+n+1$, or $2^q+1=n-1$ and $2^p=n^2+n+1$.

If $2^q+1=n^2+n+1$ then $2^q=n^2+n=n(n+1)$ which would mean that $q=n=1$, which does not work.

If $2^p=n^2+n+1$ then $2^{p+2}=4n^2+4n+4=(2n+1)^2+3$. Since squares in modulo $8$ can be $0$, $1$ or $4$, it follows that $(2n+1)^2+3$ can be $3$, $4$ or $7\pmod8$. However, since $p>1$, $2^{p+2}=0\pmod8$, so this does not work.

If $\gcd(n-1,n^2+n+1)=3$, let $n=3k+1$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then we have $$(3k+1)^3-1=3k\left((3k+1)^2+(3k+1)+1\right)=9k(3k^2+3k+1)=2^p(2^q+1)$$
Since $3\nmid2^p$, $2^q+1$ must be divisible by $9$, so $2^p=k$ and $2^q+1=9(3k^2+3k+1)$, or $2^p=3k^2+3k+1$ and $2^q+1=9k$, or $2^p=k(3k^2+3k+1)$ and $2^q+1=9$.

If $2^p=k(3k^2+3k+1)$ then $k$ and $3k^2+3k+1$ are powers of $2$, but since $\gcd(k,3k^2+3k+1)=1$, only one of these is a power of $2$. Since $k<3k^2+3k+1$, it follows that $k=1$, but then $3k^2+3k+1=7$ is not a power of $2$, so this does not work.

If $2^p=k$ and $2^q+1=9(3k^2+3k+1)$ then $2^q=27k(k+1)+8$, so $\gcd(2^p,2^q)\le8$. Since $k<9(3k^2+3k+1)$, $k=2^p$ can only be $1$, $2$, $4$, or $8$, which respectively give $2^q=62$, $168$, $548$ and $1952$, none of which work.

$2^p=3k^2+3k+1$ also cannot work because $3k^2+3k+1=3k(k+1)+1=1\pmod2$ for both $k=0$ and $k=1\pmod2$, so $3k^2+3k+1$ cannot be $2^p$ if $p\ge1$.

Overall, it can be seen that $n^3-1$ cannot be written in the form $2^p(2^q+1)$ and so no cube has three $1$s in its binary representation.

Comment: In the paragraph starting with "Since p,q>0" I don't see why the four terms should be pairwise equal, e.g. $6 \cdot 35 = 2 \cdot 105$ with 6, 35 and 2, 105 coprime and greater than 1, and yet they are not pairwise equal.

Comment: Yes, I think I got a bit confused. I guess what we could say is that $n^2+n+1=n(n+1)+1$ is always odd and so cannot share any factors with $2^p$. Then I think we must have $2^p=n-1$, which means $2^q+1=n^2+n+1$, so $q$ and $n$ must be $1$, which doesn't work.

Comment: @SaiMehta It's true that all the factors of 2 must be in $n-1$, but that doesn't mean that there can't be any odd factors in there as well. In other words, you could have $n-1=2^p\cdot r$, where $r|(2^q+1)$, and then $n^2+n+1 = (2^q+1)/r$.

Answer (score 2):

## Partial answer

First, we'll need a way to calculate the [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) of an integer (when expressed in binary).  This can be done easily in any programming language that supports bit operations.

```
def hamming(n):
    weight = 0
    while n:
        weight += n & 1
        n >>= 1
    return weight
```

Now, let $k$ be an integer and let $n = k^3$.  Assume that $n$ has a Hamming weight of 3.

Consider the remainder when $n$ is divided by $2^6 = 64$.  This is equivalent to the 6 least significant bits of $n$. By brute force, we can show that:

$$n \in \{ 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 24, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 40, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 56, 57, 59, 61, 63  \}  \pmod{64}$$

However, some of these numbers themselves have a Hamming weight of 4 or greater, and thus can't possibly be the a substring of the binary representation of $n$.  Removing these from the list gives:

$$n \in \{ 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19, 21, 24, 25, 33, 35, 37, 40, 41, 49, 56 \} \pmod{64}$$

Let's also consider the remainder when $n$ is divided by 63, since, as we discussed in the comments, this base is particularly good at detecting cubes:

$$n \in \{ 0, 1, 8, 27, 28, 35, 36, 55, 62 \} \pmod{63}$$

Let $h(n \in \mathbb{N}$) denote the Hamming weight of $n$.  Let $a$ and $b$ be the quotient and remainder when $n$ is divided by 64.  We have:

$$h(64a + b) = h(a) + h(b)$$
$$h(63a + (a + b)) = h(a) + h(b)$$

We are given that $h(n) = h(a) + h(b) = 3$.  Let's break this down into 4 cases:

- $h(a) = 0, h(b) = 3$: This requires $a=0$, and thus $n = b < 63$.  It can be shown by brute force that there is no perfect cube less than 63 that has a Hamming distance of 3.  So this cannot be the case.
- $h(a) = 1, h(b) = 2$.  This requires that $a$ be a power of 2, and thus:

  - $a \in \{ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 \} \pmod{63}$
  - $b \in \{ 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 17, 18, 20, 24, 33, 34, 36, 40, 48 \}$
  - $n \equiv a + b \in \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 28, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 40, 41, 42, 44, 48, 49, 50, 52, 56 \} \pmod{63} $
- $h(a) = 2, h(b) = 1$.  This requires that $b$ be a power of 2, and $a$ be the sum of two powers of 2.

  - $a \in \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 16, 17, 18, 20, 24, 32, 33, 34, 36, 40, 48 \} \pmod{63}$
  - $b \in \{ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 \}$
  - $n \equiv a + b \in \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 28, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 40, 41, 42, 44, 48, 49, 50, 52, 56 \} \pmod{63}$
- $h(a) = 3, h(b) = 0$.  This requires $b = 0$, so $n$ is a multiple of 64.

  - $a \in \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 28, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 40, 41, 42, 44, 48, 49, 50, 52, 56 \} \pmod{63}$
  - $b = 0$
  - $n \equiv a \in \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 28, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 40, 41, 42, 44, 48, 49, 50, 52, 56 \} \pmod{63}$

Taking the union of these cases gives us:

$$n \equiv a + b \in \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 28, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 40, 41, 42, 44, 48, 49, 50, 52, 56 \} \pmod{63}$$
$$n \equiv b \in \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 16, 17, 18, 20, 24, 32, 33, 34, 36, 40, 48 \} \pmod{64}$$

And intersecting these sets with previous results gives:

$$n \in \{ 1, 8, 28, 35, 36 \} \pmod{63}$$
$$n \in \{ 0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 17, 24, 33, 40 \} \pmod{64}$$

Or, combining these two results:

$$n \in \{ 1, 8, 64, 161, 197, 225, 280, 323, 449, 512, 721, 728, 792, 1169, 1225, 1233, 1288, 1477, 1576, 1603, 1673, 1729, 1736, 1737, 1792, 1800, 1925, 1989, 2017, 2024, 2051, 2115, 2177, 2240, 2241, 2304, 2465, 2584, 3025, 3032, 3304, 3473, 3529, 3592, 3745, 3752, 3781, 3816, 3907, 3977 \} \pmod{4032}$$

This doesn't solve your conjecture, but it can be used to reduce the brute-force search space.